# Multiple INNER JOIN from the same table in SQL

Tags: sql

How to make multiple `INNER JOIN` from the same table ?

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM ___Bookings 
INNER JOIN ___Rooms  ON ___Bookings.BOO_RoomId=___Rooms.ROO_Id 
INNER JOIN ___Kardex AS ka ON ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId=ka.___Kardex.KDX_Id 
INNER JOIN ___Kardex AS kb ON ___Bookings.BOO_BillingId=kb.___Kardex.KDX_Id 
WHERE BOO_Id=224
```

**Error message:**

## 1054 - Unknown column 'ka.___Kardex.KDX_Id' in 'on clause'

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happened when you tried the above?

Comment: `ka.KDX_Id` instead of `ka.___Kardex.KDX_Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ka.___Kardex.KDX_Id` ?

you mean

`ka.KDX_Id`

```
SELECT * FROM ___Bookings 
INNER JOIN ___Rooms  ON ___Bookings.BOO_RoomId=___Rooms.ROO_Id 
INNER JOIN ___Kardex AS ka ON ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId=ka.KDX_Id 
INNER JOIN ___Kardex AS kb ON ___Bookings.BOO_BillingId=kb.KDX_Id 
WHERE BOO_Id=224
```

Comment: It works but if `BOO_BillingId=0`, the request do not work. How to check for that please?

Comment: That's a totally different question. You might want to LEFT JOIN if there may not be results in the joining table.